# Запись int в массив byte[] (NET3.5)

Tags: c#

Как и при помощи какого метода можно записать целочисленное `int в byte[]`

Ограничен 3.5, DataInputStream/DataOutputStream - не подходят.

Предполагаемый код:

```
// Записать этот инт    
int _sizeBlock = 10489;
// В этот массив
byte[] info = new byte[4];
```

Comment: Ну вот у вас есть `int`-число `0х12345678`. Что и куда должно записаться?

Comment: Пробовал всё что попадалось на глаза, уже сбился со счёту и так ни к чему и не пришёл.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx, не?

Comment: Не понимаю. Сделать можно миллионом различных способов, вопрос в том, **какой результат вы ожидаете**?

Comment: @S.Kost, а что не ответом-то?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int _sizeBlock = 10489;

byte[] info = BitConverter.GetBytes(_sizeBlock);
```

[документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) по методу

Возможен случай, когда на компьютере используется обратный порядок для хранения байт. Необходимо проверять флаг 
[BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian(v=vs.110).aspx), если он установлен в `true` "перевернуть" байты в массиве.

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(info);
```

Comment: Голова вчера была забита к двум часам ночи. Решение плавало на поверхности. Спасибо

Comment: @Garrus_En, рад был помочь)

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(DataInt),0,ArayByt,AdrAray,4);
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы, ответ на вопрос должен быть **исчерпывающим**. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1509864/edit)».